# Not able to debug in ios Simulator

Tags: ios, debugging, react-native

I'm not able to debug im ios. I get this error in simulator: 
"Runtime is not ready for debbugging. 
-Make sure Packager server is running 
-Make sure the Javascript Debugger is running and not paused on a breackpoint or exception and try reloading again."

If I open the debug page in Chrome, the console show me this error:

> "debuggerWorker.js:18 Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute
>   'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at
>   'file:///Users/Mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F222C615-DE5C-423…e/Application/5ACB48B0-8306-460E-B6CE-FF0B5B9FEDC7/parko.app/main.jsbundle'
>   failed to load."

Any solution for this problem in ios???

Comment: tried to restart your pc? I had a similar issue where restart fixed it

Comment: In addition to @BashirSidani's question - have you ensured the packager is running correctly and not erroring out?

Answer (score 1):

When debugging the app you need to run the packager in the background. This is process sends the code to the mobile app.

To start the packager manually by running

```
react-native start
```

from the project directory.  If that command didn't work make sure you have the react native cli installed:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

To run it automatically, make sure you have a `script` tag in your `package.json`, for example mine is:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
}
```

I you use react native boiler plate, all of this should work out of the box. To get an empty react native project, follow [React-native getting started guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html):

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-ios
```

Answer (score 0):

i was using chrome for debug, but you might wanna consider downloading Nuclide, its a lot easier and faster. you don't really need to deal with environment setup

https://nuclide.io